# Get an error message while tring to rewrite ReactiveMongo + BSON to JSON in Play Framework

Tags: playframework, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I tried to use Json library to replace Bson library.
This is the original code which works.

```
case class City(name: String, population: Int)

object City {
  implicit val reader = Macros.reader[City]
}

@Singleton
class CityController @Inject()(val reactiveMongoApi: ReactiveMongoApi)(implicit exec: ExecutionContext) extends Controller with MongoController with ReactiveMongoComponents {
  def findByMinPopulation(minPop: Int) = Action.async {
    import citiesBSON.BatchCommands.AggregationFramework.Match
    val futureCitiesList: Future[List[City]] = citiesBSON.aggregate(
      Match(BSONDocument("population" -> BSONDocument("$gte" -> minPop)))
    ).map(_.head[City])
    futureCitiesList.map { cities =>
      Ok(Json.toJson(cities))
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the code using Json which compiles but get an error while running.

```
case class City(name: String, population: Int)

object City {
  implicit val formatter = Json.format[City]
}

@Singleton
class CityController @Inject()(val reactiveMongoApi: ReactiveMongoApi)(implicit exec: ExecutionContext) extends Controller with MongoController with ReactiveMongoComponents {
  def findByMinPopulation(minPop: Int) = Action.async {
    import cities.BatchCommands.AggregationFramework.Match
    val futureCitiesList: Future[List[City]] = cities.aggregate(
        Match(Json.obj("population" -> Json.obj("$gte" -> minPop)))
      ).map(_.head[City])
    futureCitiesList.map { cities =>
      Ok(Json.toJson(cities))
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the error message I've got:

> [RuntimeException: (,List(ValidationError(List(CommandError[code=59, errmsg=no such command: 'allowDiskUse', bad cmd: '{ allowDiskUse: false, explain: false, aggregate: "city", pipeline: [ { $match: { population: { $gte: 50000 } } } ], bypassDocumentValidation: false }', doc: {"ok":0,"errmsg":"no such command: 'allowDiskUse', bad cmd: '{ allowDiskUse: false, explain: false, aggregate: \"city\", pipeline: [ { $match: { population: { $gte: 50000 } } } ], bypassDocumentValidation: false }'","code":59}]),WrappedArray())))]

Comment: What version reactivemongo are you using?

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/Reactivemongo-Play-Json/issues/11

Comment: @andrey.ladniy The version is **0.11.10**. Is there a way to avoid this error?

Comment: I have no error with your code. Such error I get when I place `Group` before `Match`

Comment: Why do you use `Aggregation framework` for this simple query, not `find`?

Comment: I am just trying out aggregation framework. I am going to use aggregation framework for more complex cases later, but first I need it to work correctly. Does this mean I'll have to use BSON library?

Comment: I have no error with your piece of code. So `aggregation framework` works with Json. I tried work `aggregation framework` with json and this works fine.

Comment: I try compile your code, but have some problem: how defined `cities`? I try `val cities = reactiveMongoApi.db.collection[JSONCollection]("cities")` and all works fine.

Comment: What dependies do you have in `built.sbt` for reactivemongo?

Comment: Definition of cities:
`val cities: JSONCollection = db.collection[JSONCollection]("city")
  val citiesBSON: BSONCollection = db.collection[BSONCollection]("city")`

Comment: My sbt:
`resolvers += "Sonatype Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.12.0-SNAPSHOT")`

Comment: I try 0.12.0. Code works fine.

Comment: Thank you it works. have to clear my ivy cache.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107376/discussion-between-roger-chien-and-andrey-ladniy).

Answer (score 2):

As @andrey.ladniy said, this issue got fixed in version 0.12.0-SNAPSHOT. To use this version, update build.sbt file and add this:

```
resolvers += "Sonatype Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.12.0-SNAPSHOT"
)
```

And clear ivy cache. To do this in IntelliJ IDEA, just select "File" -> "Invalidate Caches / Restart", and select "Invalidate and Restart".

I didn't clear cache at first and got the same error even after updated to the new version.