# Mapping aggregation results using ReactiveMongo JSON

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

I'm trying to write a function that aggregates data from my MongoDB using ReactiveMongo (0.12), with Play JSON serialisation (similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36165713/how-to-use-reactivemongo-json-aggregation-framework-in-play-framework)).

So this is what I have:

```scala
   def getPopAggregate(col: JSONCollection) = {

     import col.BatchCommands.AggregationFramework.{AggregationResult, Group, Match, SumField}
     col.aggregate(
       Group(JsString("$rstId"))("totalPopulation" -> SumField("population")),
       List(Match(Json.obj("totalPopulation" -> Json.obj("$gte" -> 1000))))
     ).map(_.firstBatch)

   }
```

This outputs `Future[List[JsObject]]`, however I want to map the results to a `List` of my case class (i.e. `Future[Seq[PopAggregate]]`).

```scala
   case class PopAggregate(rstId: Option[BSONObjectID], totalPopulation: Double)

   object PopAggregate {
       implicit val popAggregateFormat = Json.format[PopAggregate]
   }
```

I hope someone can spare a moment to help me past this one. Many thanks!

Comment: Having a look at the [documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/advanced-topics/aggregation.html#places-examples), examples can be seen, such as one mapping aggregation result as `GeoPlace` (... `head[GeoPlace]`).

Comment: @cchantep thanks. The thing is I'm using the *Play Framework JSON Library* which uses JSON rather than BSON - like the question that I linked to and the example that I gave. There is not much documentation using these.

Comment: Using JSON serialization doesn't change in any way the mechanism. Have you tried it before?

Comment: This actually worked: `_.head[PopAggregate]`  instead of `_.firstBatch` that is