# Aggregate data in ReactiveMongo matching by date

Tags: date, playframework, type-conversion, reactivemongo, reactivemongo-play-json

I am trying to get an aggregate in **ReactiveMongo 0.12** and **Play Framework 2.6** (using *JSON collections* - not *BSON*) by filtering dates from a *collection* called "visitors". A typical document may look like this:

```
{ "_id": ObjectID("59c33152ca2abb344c575152"), "placeId": ObjectID("59c33152ca2abb344c575152"), "date": ISODate("2017-03-26T00:00:00Z"), "visitors": 1200 }
```

So from here I want to aggregate this data to get various *visitor* totals, averages, etc, grouping by *placeId* (which identifies the place in another *collection*) and filtering by dates after 15-05-2016.

I've based this on this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36165713/how-to-use-reactivemongo-json-aggregation-framework-in-play-framework) - without the *match* it works but with it - it does not. There isn't an error but it just doesn't work:

```
  def getVisitorAggregate(col: JSONCollection) = {

    import col.BatchCommands.AggregationFramework.{Group, Match, SumField, AvgField, MinField, MaxField}

    val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY")
    val myDate = "15-05-2016"

    val parseDate: Date = format.parse(myDate)
    val longDate: Long = parseDate.getTime

    col.aggregate(
      Group(JsString("$placeId"))(
        "totalVisitors" -> SumField("visitors"),
        "avgVisitors" -> AvgField("visitors"),
        "minVisitors" -> MinField("visitors"),
        "maxVisitors" -> MaxField("visitors")
      ),
      List(Match(Json.obj("date" -> Json.obj("$gte" -> JsNumber(longDate)))))
    )
      .map(_.head[VisitorAggregate])

  }
```

I have looked and tested for many hours online and I cannot find the correct syntax but this will be simple for someone who knows I'm sure. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question here but now that I have figured this out I really want to clarify to others how this is done using *Aggregate*. Ultimately there were two parts to this question.

**1) what is the syntax of querying dates?**

As @AndriyKuba mentioned and I had seen in the [documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/json/overview.html) yet not fully understood; the query is formulated like this:

```
   Json.obj("date" -> Json.obj("$gte" -> Json.obj("$date" -> JsNumber(longDate))))
```

**2) how do I *match* a query within an *Aggregate*?**

This is more of a question of the order of the query. I was originally trying to use *match* after grouping and aggregating the data - which is (obviously) only going to filter the data after. As I wanted to first get a date range and then aggregate that data I had to *match* first - this also meant that some of the syntax had to change accordingly:

```
  def getVisitorAggregate(col: JSONCollection) = {

    import col.BatchCommands.AggregationFramework.{Group, Match, SumField, AvgField, MinField, MaxField}

    val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY")
    val myDate = "15-05-2016"

    val parseDate: Date = format.parse(myDate)
    val longDate: Long = parseDate.getTime

    col.aggregate(
      Match(Json.obj("date" -> Json.obj("$gte" -> Json.obj("$date" -> JsNumber(longDate))))),
      List(Group(JsString("$rstId"))(
        "totalVisitors" -> SumField("visitors"),
        "avgVisitors" -> AvgField("visitors"),
        "minVisitors" -> MinField("visitors"),
        "maxVisitors" -> MaxField("visitors")
      ))
    )
      .map(_.head[VisitorAggregate])

  }
```

Really frustrating that there isn't more documentation out there on using the *Play Framework* with *ReactiveMongo* as there are a lot of instances of trying to fathom syntax and logic.

Comment: As I remember/can see, on one side every element of the solution is mentioned on the documentation, on the other side the documentation is open.

Answer (score 1):

`ISODate` is a mongodb type, and `Model.aggregate` does not cast the arguments, so `"date" -> Json.obj("$gte" -> JsNumber(longDate))` is wrong.

You need to use a type that will be converted to the `ISODate`, I am pretty sure it is not `JsNumber`.

It is a `BSONDateTime` type would you use `BSON`, but you do not.

According [to documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/json/overview.html) it must be a

> `JsObject` with a `$date` `JsNumber` field with the timestamp (milliseconds)
>   as value

So solution can be (I did not verify):

```
Match(Json.obj("date" -> Json.obj("$gte" -> Json.obj("$date" -> JsNumber(longDate)))))
```

Comment: I saw that documentation and already tried this but it isn't the solution Andriy. Just made sure now and it doesn't work